Cross-platform waveform viewer with ability to combine wav and vcd tracks, and cut and move parts of tracks?
I'm looking for a cross-platform, preferably open-source, GUI waveform viewer, which would allow me to, for example:

Load (say) 2 "analog" tracks from a .wav file in a project/session
Additionally, import/load (say) 2 "digital" tracks from a .vsd in the same project/session

This would require specifying the sampling rate of the project/session, and automatic resampling of the imported data, if it has a sampling rate different from the project/session


Allow possibility to move (say) first track of the .wav, and second track of the .vcd, interactively (with the mouse or keyboard) left or right (in time)
Allow possibility to interactively mark and cut arbitrary portions of arbitrary tracks

From what I know, PulseView (image src):

... supports loading both .wav and .vcd (and so can visualize both analog and digital waveforms), and has quite a fast zoom, along with markers and protocol decoders, so it would have been ideal - however:

If you load a .wav in an empty session, and afterwards try to import .vcd in the same session, the contents from the .wav in the session will be erased, and only the contents of the .vcd will be present
There is no way to move/reposition tracks left/right (in time)
There is no way to mark and cut portions of tracks

I have seen capability to import data from different files in the same project/session in Audacity, where you have to specify a project sampling rate first (so then, even if you import files with data sampled at different sampling rate, they will be automatically resampled) - however, as an audio editor, it only supports .wav and related "analog" audio file formats.
Audacity supports the concept of "clips" (image src):


... which can then be moved with the mouse (image src):

So, essentially I'm looking for a combination of PulseView and Audacity in a single GUI software. Is there anything like this out there?
